# Not able to profile local tomcat with visualvm and the same tempdir

Tags: linux, tomcat, profiler, visualvm

I can't see visualvm profile result on local tomcat on linux box.
I see only status - 0 classes instrumented and no profiling results

RedHat ELS 6.4
java  1.7.0_25-b15
Tomcat and visualvm started with the same java.io.tempdir=/tmp

/tmp dir has hsperfata_ directory and jfluidbuf....tmp files.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve my issue with visualvm from http://visualvm.java.net/ not from jdk.